# Different definitions for consistent set of sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In my logic class, we were given the following definition for a set of sentences being consistent in first order logic:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a set of sentences in some underlying language $L$. The set $\Gamma$ is *inconsistent* if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ for all $L$ sentences $\varphi$. The set $\Gamma$ is *consistent* if it is not inconsistent.

We were then given several equivalent definitions. In particular, we were told that

> $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ is *inconsistent* if and only if $\Gamma \vdash \neg \gamma$.

I am trying to verify this on my own, and can easily show that if $\Gamma \vdash \neg \gamma$ then $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ is inconsistent, but I am having more trouble with the other direction. I feel like it should be relatively simple, but I do not have much experience with formal logic.

All of my attempts run into a wall where I feel like I need to prove the following: if $\Sigma \cup \{\sigma\} \vdash \neg \sigma$ then $\Sigma \vdash \neg \sigma$, which makes intuitive sense, but which I cannot formalize.

Comment: I don't think the statement about $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ is a definition.

Comment: Does $\vdash$ have a semantic meaning (to do with models) or a syntactic meaning (to do with formal proofs)?

Comment: If it is the syntactic meaning, this might help you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem

Comment: Essentially, it's a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018833/if-gamma-cup-neg-varphi-is-inconsistent-then-gamma-vdash-varphi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to use the deduction theorem and remember some useful definitions:

**Claim**: If $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ is inconsistent then $\Gamma \vdash \neg \gamma$

**Proof**: Suppose that $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\}$ is inconsistent. Then, by the definition of an inconsistent set above, $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\} \vdash \varphi$ for all $L$ sentences $\varphi$. Hence, $\Gamma \cup \{\gamma\} \vdash \bot$ and, by deduction theorem, $\Gamma \vdash \gamma \to \bot$. Now, by the usual definition of $\neg$, it means that $\Gamma \vdash \neg \gamma$.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

The above definitions of *consistency* are expressed in terms of the *derivability* relation : $\vdash$.

Thus, in order to study their properties, we need the rules of the *proof system*.

Your definition of *consistency* is one of the two "natural" definition of *consistency*, the other being :

> $\Gamma$ is *consistent* if there is no formula $\varphi$ such that both : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

Alternatively, if the language has the symbol $\bot$ (the *falsum*), we can state it as :

> $\Gamma$ is *consistent* if $\Gamma \nvdash \bot$.

In any case, we can prove :

> The following conditions are equivalent:
>
> > *(i)* $\Gamma \nvdash \bot$
> >
> > *(ii)* For no $\varphi$, $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ and $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$,
> >
> > *(iii)* There is at least one formula $\varphi$ such that $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

Finally, we can prove :

> *(a)* if $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$,
>
> *(b)* if $\Gamma \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

To prove it, we will use as *proof system* the *Natural Deduction* one; in it we have $\bot$ as primitive and the definition of $\lnot \varphi$ as $\varphi \rightarrow \bot$.

We have also the rules for $\lnot$ :

> $$\frac {\bot } \varphi \quad \text{(EFQ)}$$
>
> $$\frac {\lnot \varphi \vdash \bot} \varphi \quad \text{(RAA)}$$

We have to use also the rules for managing $\rightarrow$ :

> $$\frac {\varphi \rightarrow \psi \quad \varphi } \psi \quad \text{($\rightarrow$-E)}$$
>
> $$\frac {\varphi \vdash \psi } {\varphi \rightarrow \psi} \quad \text{($\rightarrow$-I)}$$

If we apply the $\rightarrow$-E rule with $\bot$ in place of $\psi$, due to the fact that $\varphi \rightarrow \bot$ is $\lnot \varphi$, we can derive a new rule for $\lnot$ :

> $$\frac {\lnot \varphi \quad \varphi } \bot \quad \text{($\lnot$-I)}$$

---

We assume the following definition :  $\Gamma$ is *inconsistent* if $\Gamma \vdash \bot$.

Thus, form the assumption that $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ is **inconsistent**, we have :

> $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \} \vdash \bot$;

then, applying *RAA* rule we have :

> > $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

If we assume that $\Gamma \cup \{ \varphi \}$ is **inconsistent**, we have :

> $\Gamma \cup \{ \varphi \} \vdash \bot$;

then, applying $\rightarrow$-I rule we have :

> > $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \varphi$.

---

---

*Note*

This proof can be adapted to others *proof systems*.

For an *Hilbert-style* one, we can use the definition :

> $\Gamma$ is *inconsistent* if for every formula $\varphi$ : $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.

We need some preliminary *Lemmas*; we have to prove that :

> $\lnot \varphi → \varphi \vdash \varphi$

[see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017887/need-hints-prove-neg-alpha-to-alpha-to-alpha-using-axiom-1-2-3-an) for a proof].

With this result we can prove :

> if $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \} \vdash \psi$ and $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \} \vdash \lnot \psi$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

and finally apply it to prove :

> if $\Gamma \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ is inconsistent, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.