# How can I prove this using ONLY (L1, L2, L3, MP) by 19 steps

Tags: logic

How can I prove (┐p→p)→p using ONLY (L1, L2, L3, MP) by 19 steps?
Sorry for not declaring the Axiom. Here is my Axiom, which is different from the one below:

[Need Hints Prove "$((\neg \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha) $" Using Axiom 1,2,3 and MP and deduction theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017887/need-hints-prove-neg-alpha-to-alpha-to-alpha-using-axiom-1-2-3-an)

```
L1: p→(q→p)
L2: (p→(q→r))→((p→q)→(p→r))
L3: (┐p→┐q)→(q→p)
```

Thanks a lot for answering me again.

Comment: What are L1, L2 and L3? Presumably not the axioms of Lukasiewicz logic, because your formula isn't provable in Lukasiewicz logic $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: You can find it in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017887/need-hints-prove-neg-alpha-to-alpha-to-alpha-using-axiom-1-2-3-an).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: thanks - but how on earth is anybody supposed to know that? The relevant pointers should be in the question above.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I have changed my problem to be different from that one. Could you please help me to think of this problem? Sorry for not declaring the Axiom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to start with the proof of :

> > (A) $ \ \vdash \alpha \rightarrow \alpha$.

(1) $\alpha → ((\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) → \alpha)$ --- from Ax1

(2) $(\alpha → ((\alpha \rightarrow \alpha) → \alpha)) → ((\alpha → (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) → (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha))$ --- from Ax2

(3) $(\alpha → (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)) → (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *modus ponens*

(4) $\alpha → (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha)$ --- from Ax1

> (5) $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha$ --- from 3) and 4) by *modus ponens*.

---

We need :

> > (B) $ \ \vdash \alpha \to \beta, \beta \to \gamma \vdash \alpha \to \gamma$.

(1) $\alpha \to \beta$

(2) $\beta \to \gamma$

(3) $(\beta \to \gamma) \to (\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma))$ --- by Ax1

(4) $\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)$ --- from 2) and 3) by *modus ponens*

(5) $(\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma))$ --- by Ax2

(6) $(\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma)$ --- from 4) and 5) by *modus ponens*

> (7) $\alpha \to \gamma$ --- from 1) and 6) by *modus ponens*.

---

We need :

> > (C) $ \ \vdash \lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$.

(1) $\lnot \alpha \to (\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha)$ --- by Ax1

(2) $(\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- by Ax3

> (3) $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ --- from 1) and 2) by (B).

---

We need :

> > (D) $ \ \vdash (\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\beta \to \alpha)$.

(1) $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \lnot \beta)$ --- by (C)

(2) $(\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \lnot \beta)) \to ((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\lnot \alpha \to \lnot \beta))$ --- by Ax2

(3) $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\lnot \alpha \to \lnot \beta)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *mp*

(4) $(\lnot \alpha \to \lnot \beta) \to (\beta \to \alpha)$ --- by Ax3

> (5) $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\beta \to \alpha)$ --- from 3) and 4) by (B).

---

Finally :

> > (E) $ \ \vdash (\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha)$.

(1) $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to ((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha)$ --- by (D)

(2) $((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to ((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha)) \to (((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\lnot \alpha \to \alpha)) \to ((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha))$ --- by Ax2

(3) $((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\lnot \alpha \to \alpha)) \to ((\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha)$ --- from 1) and 2) by *mp*

(4) $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to (\lnot \alpha \to \alpha)$ --- by (A)

> (5) $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha$ --- from 3) and 4) by *mp*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me~

Comment: Wait a minute, I think there is something wrong with (D2) which should be (¬α→(α→β))→((¬α→α)→(¬α→β))