# How to prove ⊢ (B → ¬B) → ¬B using an informal deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms, formal-proofs, hilbert-calculus

So I need to prove **⊢ (B → ¬B) → ¬B**

I can use the Modus ponus (MP) rule, and deduction theorem (DT). And I have these 3 axioms:

1. α → (β → α) --- (A1)
2. (α → (β → γ)) → ((α → β) → (α → γ)) --- (A2)
3. (¬β → ¬α) → ((¬β → α) → β) --- (A3)

The first step I did was to use DT to simplify what I need to proof to (B → ¬B) ⊢ ¬B. And then I'm stuck.

Does anyone know how to go on to solve the formal proof? Or any hints on how to start would be greatly appreciated! Also, as a general rule, how do you know which axioms to use to solve the proof? Is there any particular pattern that I should look out for? If not, it seems very trial and error to me and I always get stuck at the start of the proof.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @J.W.Tanner No, it does not.

Comment: What does $\neg$ mean for you? If it means $B \to \bot$, then you can use the deduction theorem again.

Comment: What is an "informal deduction" ?

Comment: Ver similar [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1017887/need-hints-prove-neg-alpha-to-alpha-to-alpha-using-axiom-1-2-3-an)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the third axiom says that if the negation of a proposition implies some other proposition and it's negation, then the original proposition holds.  Note also that the negation of $\lnot$B is $\lnot$$\lnot$B.

So, assume $\lnot$$\lnot$B.  Deduce B (hint assume $\lnot$B next).  And I hope you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

First:

$1. \ B \ Assume$

$2. \ B \to (B \to B) \ Ax. 1$

$3. \ B \to B \ MP \ 1,2$

$4. B \ MP \ 1,3$

So: $B \vdash B$

By DT: $\vdash B \to B$ (ID)

Next:

$1. \neg \neg B \ Assume$

$2. \neg \neg B \to (\neg B \to \neg \neg B) \ Ax. 1$

$3. \neg B \to \neg \neg B \ MP \ 1,2$

$4. (\neg B \to \neg \neg B) \to ((\neg B \to \neg B) \to B \ Ax.3$

$5. (\neg B \to \neg B) \to B \ MP \ 3,4$

$6. \neg B \to \neg B \ ID$

$7. B \ MP \ 5,6$

So: $\neg \neg B \vdash B$

So, by DT: $\vdash \neg \neg B \to B$ (DN)

Then:

$1. A \to B \ Assume$

$2. B \to C \ Assume$

$3. A \ Assume$

$4. B \ MP \ 1,3$

$5. C \ MP \ 2,4$

So: $A \to B, B \to C, A \vdash C$

So, by DT: $A \to B, B \to C \vdash A \to C$ (HS)

Finally:

$1. B \to \neg B \ Assume$

$2. (\neg \neg B \to \neg \neg B) \to ((\neg \neg B \to \neg B) \to \neg B) \ Ax.3$

$3. \neg \neg B \to \neg \neg B \ ID$

$4. (\neg \neg B \to \neg B) \to \neg B \ MP \ 2,3$

$5. \neg \neg B \to B \ DN$

$6. \neg \neg B \to \neg B \ HS \ 1,5$

$7. \neg B \ MP \ 4,6$

So: $B \to \neg B \vdash \neg B$

So, by DT: $ \vdash (B \to \neg B) \to \neg B$

Comment: Oh wow the number of steps involved, thank you so so much!

Comment: But, what does ID, DN and HS in your solution mean?

Comment: @Djy They refer to the earlier proved results that, as such, can be taken as Lemma's. For example, with the first proof I proved $\vdash B \to B$ ... but this '$B$' can be taken as a variable: the proof would have worked for *any* statement. So, for example, in the second proof, on line 6, I use ID to get $\neg B \to \neg B$. See how this works?

Comment: @Djy If you're asking about what the letters stand for: ID : Identity; DN: Double Negation; HS: Hypothetical Syllogism

Comment: Ah yes I sort of get it, thank you thank you!